# Элементы массива выводятся некорректно

Tags: массивы, pascal, pascalabc.net

Я хочу вывести элементы массива, который заполняет пользователь. Вывод хочу организовать как матрицу. Проблема в том, что этого не происходит. Хотя, воде, по логике всё так. В чем может быть проблема?

Ввод:

```
Введите число строк 1-й матрицы - A (<=50)--> 2
Введите число столбцов 1-й матрицы - A (<=50)--> 2
Введите число столбцов 2-й матрицы - B (<=50)--> 2
Введите 1-ю матрицу (A):
Введите A[1,1] --> 1
Введите A[1,2] --> 2
Введите A[32,1] --> 
Введите A[2,2] --> 4
Введите 2-ю матрицу (B):
Введите B[1,1] --> 5
Введите B[1,2] --> 6
Введите B[2,1] --> 6
Введите B[2,2] --> 6
```

Вывод:

```
Матрица А.
[1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]  [1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]Матрица А.
[1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]  [3,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]Матрица А.
[3,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]  [1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]Матрица А.
[3,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]  [3,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]Матрица B.
[5,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]  [5,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]Матрица B.
[5,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]  [6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]Матрица B.
[6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]  [5,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]Матрица B.
[6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]  [6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
---- Результат: -----
   17.00   18.00
   39.00   42.00
```

Код:

```
Const Max=50;

Var AA,BB,CC: array [1..Max,1..Max] of Double;
  ii,jj,kk,nn,mm,ll : integer; Summa: double;

begin
  write('Введите число строк 1-й матрицы - A (<=50)--> ');readln(NN);
  write('Введите число столбцов 1-й матрицы - A (<=50)--> ');readln(KK);
  write('Введите число столбцов 2-й матрицы - B (<=50)--> ');readln(MM);
  writeln('Введите 1-ю матрицу (A):');
  for ii:=1 to nn do
  for jj:=1 to kk do
    begin
      write('Введите A[',ii,',',jj,'] --> ');
      readln(AA[ii,jj]);
    end;

  writeln('Введите 2-ю матрицу (B):');
  for ii:=1 to kk do
  for jj:=1 to mm do
   begin write('Введите B[',ii,',',jj,'] --> '); readln(BB[ii,jj]);
   end;

   {проблема}
   for ii:=1 to nn do
   for jj:=1 to kk do
   begin
     writeln('Матрица А.');
     write(AA[ii], '  ', AA[jj]);
   end;

   for ii:=1 to kk do
   for jj:=1 to mm do
   begin
     writeln('Матрица B.');
     write(BB[ii], '  ', BB[jj]);
   end;

  {Вычисляем элементы матрицы-результата}

    for ii:=1 to nn do
    for jj:=1 to mm do
      begin
        Summa:= 0;
        for ll:= 1 to kk do
          Summa:= Summa + AA[ii,ll]*BB[ll,jj];
          CC[ii,jj] := Summa;
      end;
{Выводим матрицу-результат:}
  writeln();
  writeln('---- Результат: -----');
  for ii:=1 to nn do
    begin
      for jj:=1 to mm do
        write(CC[ii,jj]:8:2);
      writeln;
    end;
readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Матрица же двумерная, а вот это `write(AA[ii], '  ', AA[jj]);` выводит две **строки** матрицы **целиком** - а полный размер же 50. Выводите только нужные элементы

```
 writeln('Матрица А.');
 for ii:=1 to nn do begin
   for jj:=1 to kk do
     write(AA[ii, jj], ' ');
   writeln;
 end;
```

P.S. Ещё такой момент - при наличии двузначных, например, чисел форматирование собьётся. Поэтом лучше использовать вывод в поля фиксированной ширины

```
write(AA[ii, jj]: 4);
```